# Image processing on GPU

Tags: image-processing, gpu

I have a prospect project for Image processing on GPU, I know some C&C++ but i never spend time on image processing and GPU programming.

Is it a hard project for a 3 months?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is asking for estimate of how long a project may take.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what image processing you need to do. Some image processing is sufficiently complex that doing it in 3 months is almost out of the question, regardless of how you do it. Other things are sufficiently simple that you can copy some code from the OpenGL Red Book (for only one example), compile it, and be on your way.

We'll *hope* you're dealing with something between those extremes, but you haven't said enough to really even guess.

Comment: In project description it's said that simple image processing will be done. But a friend said that i needed a Nvidia card for doing GPU programming but  i only have Intel 945 or something else on-board card. I don't think i can do this project

Answer (score 0):

There are some frameworks, but I haven't used them. Look at [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA).

Answer (score 0):

To start with, what exactly is the functionality required? We have developed CUVI Lib (CUDA for Vision and Imaging) which is publicly available at: http://www.cuvilib.com

If it's something of interest for us, we would definitely love to team up depending upon the resources we have at that moment. Drop me an email at: salman@tunacode.com

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to decide How you will interact with GPU - through GPGPU libs,- such as CUDA/OpenCL or just through Pixel Shaders,- such as GLSL/HLSL.